# Find object in arraylist without loop

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Good morning friends, I have a question / problem

I currently have the following code:

```
ArrayList<BeanRelConsumoProducao> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<BeanRelConsumoProducao>();
.... // add to dataBeanList

for (int i=0; i<dataBeanList.size(); i++)
{
    BeanRelConsumoProducao bean = dataBeanList.get(i);

    String nomeprod = bean.getProdNome();                       

    if(nomeprod.equals(bomLine.getM_Product().getName())) 
   {

     bean.setProdConsumo(bean.getProdConsumo().add(consumo.multiply(bomLine.getQtyBOM())));
        taNaLista = true; // item found
    }
}
```

however this loop is inside another loop and the dataBeanList has many objects, leaving the query very slow.

How can I improve performance to find an object faster and make my code slower?

This code is for comparing product listing material items. (BOM)

Thank you.

Comment: I think you mean "make my code faster" not "make my code slower". Apart from that: Can the object only appear once inside your list, or mutliple times? If it's just once you could at least break your loop after you found it.

Comment: Keep your products in a hashmap instead of a list. You're basically looking them up by name anyway.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method ?

Comment: You can remove String nomeprod with if(dataBeanList.get(i).getProdNome().equals(bomLine.getM_Product().getName())) {....}  here i assuming your dataBeanList not contain any null value. you can modified inner if in same way

Comment: You can cache `bomLine.getM_Product().getName()` outside the loop as it doesn't change.

Comment: I changed from ArrayList to HashMap according to some suggestions and worked out.

But I need to send the data to an iReport report and I am not able to convert the HashMap data now ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming the bean names are unique*, you could use some kind of `Map`:

```
ArrayList<BeanRelConsumoProducao> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<BeanRelConsumoProducao>();
.... // add to dataBeanList

//Create a map of names to beans (Java 8):
LinkedHashMap<String,BeanRelConsumoProducao> beansByName = dataBeanList.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(BeanRelConsumoProducao::getProdNome, bean->bean);

//directly grab the desired bean:
BeanRelConsumoProducao prod = beansByName.get(bomLine.getM_Product().getName());

if(prod!=null) {
    //was found
    taNaLista = true;
} else {
    //not found.
}
```

Other notes:

- You should store the map `beansByName` for as long as necessary (do not recompute for each BOM item if it isn't necessary).
- You need to keep this map up to date if you make any further changes to dataBeanList!
- I have used a `LinkedHashMap`, as it retains the original ordering. If you don't ever care about the ordering, just use a `HashMap`

If you cannot use a `Map`, the very least you should do, as per comments, is to shortcut the loop as soon as you have found your item. You can do this by adding a `break;` after `taNaLista = true;`

**Edit:**

> ```
> HashMap<String, BeanRelConsumoProducao> dataBeanList = new HashMap(); 
>
> BeanRelConsumoProducao beanHash = dataBeanList.get(bomLine.getM_Product().getName());  
>
> if(beanHash != null) {
>   taNaLista = true;
> }
> ```
>
> But, I have a problem on:
>
> ```
> JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);
> ```

Presumably the constructor for `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` expects a `List`. Since our 'list' has changed to be a `Map`, they are no longer type compatible. If you have access to the source code of `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`, you could do the following:

1. Change its constructor to accept an argument of type `Collection`.
2. Change the above to:

   ```
   JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList.values());
   ```

If on the other hand you cannot change `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`, you will need to convert the values in the map back into a list, for example:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(new ArrayList(dataBeanList.values()));
```

Comment: I changed from ArrayList to HashMap according to some suggestions and worked out.

But I need to send the data to an iReport report and I am not able to convert the HashMap data now ... any suggestions?

HashMap<String, BeanRelConsumoProducao> dataBeanList = new HashMap(); 

BeanRelConsumoProducao beanHash = dataBeanList.get(bomLine.getM_Product().getName());  
      
if(beanHash != null) {
 taNaLista = true;
}

But, I have a problem on:

JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);

Answer (score 0):

I changed from ArrayList to HashMap according to some suggestions and worked out.

But I need to send the data to an iReport report and I am not able to convert the HashMap data now ... any suggestions?

```
HashMap<String, BeanRelConsumoProducao> dataBeanList = new HashMap(); 

BeanRelConsumoProducao beanHash = dataBeanList.get(bomLine.getM_Product().getName());  

if(beanHash != null) {
    taNaLista = true;
}
```

But, I have a problem on:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);
```